# Android setting action bar from child intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Excuse me, I just wanted to know.
Is that possible to set action bar from `child intent`?

In my case, my main activity is `SherlockActivity`, but it's using a `tab` host.
then I'm adding a tabspec from Intent which using sherlockActivity too.
And then I want to set the action bar from that tabspec's intent.

If is that possible to do, may I know how? because that  makes my application meet an error.

`08-16 10:30:00.470: E/AndroidRuntime(16137): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{}: java.lang.NullPointerException`

this is my main activity :

public class MainActivity extends SherlockActivity {

```
private LocalActivityManager lam;
private TextView tv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

    lam = new LocalActivityManager(this, false);
    lam.dispatchCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.header);

    View v = getSupportActionBar().getCustomView();
    tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.headerTitle);
    tv.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(AlumniApplication.getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/LLNITRO_.ttf"));
    tv.setText("Title");

    setTab();
}

private void setTab(){      
    TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.main_tabhost);
    tabHost.setup(lam);

    TabSpec com = tabHost.newTabSpec("community");
    com.setIndicator(getTabIndicator(R.drawable.com_tab));
    com.setContent(new Intent(AlumniApplication.getContext(), CommunityActivity.class));

    tabHost.addTab(com);
}

private View getTabIndicator(int srcId){
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(AlumniApplication.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.tab_image_layout, null);

    ImageView iv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.tab_image);
    iv.setImageResource(srcId);

    return v;
}
```

}

and then I wanted to set the the action bar from that child intent

public class CommunityActivity extends SherlockActivity {

```
private LocalActivityManager lam;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tab_above_layout);
}
```

}

but when I do that, It gone error.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: I already edit the question by attching the code

Answer (score 0):

if you want to call a method of your activity (which is hosting the fragment) out of a child-fragment, you will need to get the refernece to the hosting activity. With `getActivity()` you can get this connection. Now you can call methods of the activity inside the fragment.

for example:

```
getActivity().setTitle(R.string.my_actionbar_title);
```